# Search field broken on phone

Tags: bug, search-box

This started 1-2 days ago.

The top bar now shows two search icons:

[image: Top bar]

When I tap the left one:

[image: left tap]

When I tap the right one:

[image]

The keyboard does pop up, but I have to type blindly. What I enter isn't shown on the screen. And if I enter for example "python", I end up searching for "nohtyp". Huh? It's not April 1st yet!

[image]

Comment: Also [reported on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398680/too-small-search-bar-and-the-search-icon-magnifying-glass-is-shown-twice-while-v)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat The common factor is that they and I both have 18 unread messages!

Comment: That's just a coincidence, I can reproduce this same problem. The problem can be seen when the size / width of the page is small enough.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yeah, just kidding. The coincidence amused me.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem

Comment: Plus one - same thing on my iPhone. Two search icons / fields neither of which is usable. Searching is now impossible on the phone.

Comment: Me three. Very annoying.

Comment: Seems to be back down to one search icon again.

Comment: There Can Be Only One.